# Android studio sqlite query unexpected error

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, android-sqlite

[image: screenshot]got a unexpected error in this query, I don't know how to solve this problem, please help me anyone.

I run in sql browser this query is working, but I don't know how enter android format method 
 select PARTY, count(PARTY) from voter_table group by PARTY;

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Vote.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "voter_table";
    public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
    public static final String COL_2 = "PARTY";
    public static final String COL_3 = "USERNAME";
public int getCountData() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor res1 = db.rawQuery("select" +COL_2+", count("+COL_2+") from" +TABLE_NAME+ "group by" +COL_2;);
        res1.moveToFirst();
        int recCount = res1.getInt(0);
        res1.close();
        db.close();
        return recCount;
    }
```

Comment: please show your error log

Comment: Show error logcat and also add space before and after 'FROM'

Comment: @ Mochamad Taufik Hidayat here i attached screenshot please check it

Comment: There are errors in your given query like add plus before table name, bracket inside double quotation mark.  Try this -     String query = "SELECT " +COL_2 +",COUNT(" +COL_2 +") FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " GROUP BY " + COL_2 ;

Comment: @Jaiprakash Soni  i attached screenshot please check it

Comment: Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. If you post images of code or error messages make sure you also copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly. Please see [Why may I not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/208273) - the same reasoning applies to error messages as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
static final String TABLE_NAME = "voter_table";
    public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
    public static final String COL_2 = "PARTY";
    public static final String COL_3 = "USERNAME";
    String query = "SELECT " +COL_2 +",COUNT(" +COL_2 +") FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " GROUP BY " + COL_2 ;
```

Comment: i got a error Cursor res1 = db.rawQuery("select" +COL_2+",count("+COL_2+") from" +TABLE_NAME+"group by" +COL_2;);

Comment: please check my screenshot

Comment: Try this - Cursor res1 = db.rawQuery("select " +COL_2+",count("+COL_2+") from " +TABLE_NAME+" group by " +COL_2);